# how to save EditText's value after performing an other activity

Tags: java, android

i have my first activity with two EditText fields with hint's as first name and last name, when ever i go to my second activity and return to my first activity by a widget button the EditText fields in my first activity gets reset.

SIMPLY i want my EditText fields to remain same in my first activity as i re-visit my first activity from my second activity.

### MY MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

public void onButton1Click(View v)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent (this,MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

### }

### My MainActivity2.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

}
```

### }

SOLUTION - i changed my second activity to this. just added reference to my Button and applied an onClickListener with onBackPressed(); code.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);  

     Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);   //gave reference of button in second activity
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //and applied an onClickListener with code onBackpressed();
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
        }
    });
}
```

---

Really Really thnx to @Narendra Sorathiya for his guidance.

Comment: Did you read into `Intent`'s?

Comment: just save them in sharedpref  and restore

Comment: @MuratK. what do you mean?

Comment: @jagapathi can you share the code  with me i am a beginner in java so its v.hard for me to manage that things on my own.

Comment: can you share your code? adding an activity to the stack shouldn't reset previous activities, so I think something else is in play

Comment: @AsgharAli You'll get better answers and feedback if you always include an example of your problem.  The smaller and simpler the better.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AsgharAli it will be better if you can share some code snippet of how you are launching the activities.

Comment: @Matt it's my first time posting in any forum so i had no idea how to make it smaller and more understandable but next time i will try that it should be in a perfect way.

Comment: @RobVoisey sorry for late response, now i have added my both activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open secondActivity like below,

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

do not open 1st Activity from 2nd Activity, just need to back press.

Comment: Yeah It Worked, But is there any way that without pressing the back button i should have the same result? like creating a button in second activity  to visit the First Activity and have the same result.

Comment: just add onBackPressed() inside that button click event

Comment: should i put it in clickeventlistener?

Comment: Narendra but not the exact answer i am looking for.

Comment: Yes, you need to put it onClickListener

Comment: yeah it worked, Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

try this
**declare all variavle at top of activity**

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String FNAME = "fname";
public static final String LNAME = "lname";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

**write this code when you move to your next activity**

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// store login data in sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(FNAME, edittext.getText());
editor.putString(LNAME, edittext2.getText());
editor.commit(); //save data in  sharedpreferences
```

**write this code in your oncreate method after you bind your controls**

and get data from sharedprefrence like this

```
String fname= prefs.getString(FNAME, "");
String fname= prefs.getString(LNAME, "");
```

than set it to your editext like this

```
editext.setText(fname);
editext2.setText(lname);
```

**let me know in case of any query**

Comment: in addition to nilesh code , do not forget to put null checks before setting text to edittext

Comment: where should i write the first codes that you have given? in my first activity or the second? i am a new beginner so its little hard for me to manage this codes.

Comment: write this code in your first activity 
1. deaclere variable at top of your activity

Comment: i get error "cannot resolve symbol" on edittext1,edittext2 and on both prefs,

Comment: follow this stpes

Comment: 1.declare all variable at top
2. than use shared pref

Comment: sorry bro but looks i am still jumbling,

Comment: where do you tribling